# Invisible characters in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

At the last few days anytime when I am writing a query, it is not working.

But as soon as I replace the full query with one from my old files and change the necessary variables, it is working.. They are totally the same. Maybe these are invisible characters but always when i am writing? how can I prevent this? I am not writing sample code, because any `mysql_query("SELECT...` and `while($...` I am writing by my own is not working.

(by the way I am using OSX if it is matters)

PS: I heard that `mysql_query` is not the good way, but I will improve myself.

Example code:

```
$users_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$_SESSION[user_id]'");
while($users = mysql_fetch_array($users_query))
  {
$id         = $users['id'];
$username   = $users['username'];
}
```

This wasn't working. After I overwrote this with my older query and changed the names, everything started to work, but the final result looks the exact same, with the same amount of characters.:(

UPDATE:::
Now I know that invisible character causing the problem, (picture is not attached due to lack of reputation) but how can I prevent this? Few weeks ago this wasn't a problem.

Comment: Without seeing how you're executing the query and some example variable values, we can't really help.

Comment: Write it again without copy paste.

Comment: @AmalMurali, as I mentioned, none of the query working which i write without overwrite with pasted content, so it is unnecessary to give example, but i will modify the question in 2 minute.
Mihai, without copy/paste, they are not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everybody but at the same time, thanks for helps.
The problem caused by a character which is inserted by pressing the ALT and SPACE at the same time. for making a * in the query you need to press ALT+Shift+?(Question mark) together if you are using OSX. Fast typing made me not to release the ALT in the right time. Thank You, for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue when copying files from Windows into Mac OS. you open the file in Vi/Vim and do `:set list` to make vi show invisible extra characters and remove them.

Comment: I wasnt copying files from windows, issue appears when i am writing a code. You can read what caused the problem :) thanks anyway!